# Easily Validate a CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am trying to elegantly validate a CheckBoxList in ASP.NET webforms.

Problem:  Unknown server tag 'cc:ValidateableCheckBoxList'.

```
namespace fmwebapp1.UserControls
{
    [ValidationPropertyAttribute("ValidateableProperty")]
    public class ValidateableCheckBoxList : CheckBoxList
    {
        public string ValidateableProperty
        {
            get { return (this.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).Count() > 0) ? "something was selected" : ""; }
        }
    }
}
```

In the same namespace as my aspx file:

```
 <%@ Register Namespace="fmwebapp1.UserControls" Assembly="ValidateableCheckBoxList" TagPrefix="cc" %>   
<cc:ValidateableCheckBoxList runat="server" ID="cblFindTheSite">
                                        <asp:ListItem>The Press</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>blah1</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>blah2</asp:ListItem>
                                                                                </asp:CheckBoxList>
                                    <div class="validators">
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvTest" ControlToValidate="cblFindTheSite" Text="Failed validation" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: what does the referenced assembly look like in your wep app? is it called "ValidateableCheckBoxList"? My guess is the "Assembly" attribute in your register directive is wrong. It needs to match the assembly name in the referenced assembly.

Comment: Awesome that was it.. cheers!  Put in an answer and I'll mark it as right.. thanks RPM1984

Comment: no worries. I added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the assembly referenced in the Web Application matches the "Assembly" attribute in your Register directive.